# MSBuild Zip64 Causes Jenkins to run out of Disk Space

Tags: c#, jenkins, msbuild, zip

We're using MS Build on our Jenkins server.  https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks/blob/master/Source/MSBuild.Community.Tasks/Zip.cs

I have a project that is raising the error "Compressed or Uncompressed size, or offset exceeds the maximum value. Consider setting the UseZip64WhenSaving property on the ZipFile instance" so I set the Zip64 property to true.  When I do this, then a different error is raised "There is not enough space on the disk"

This has gone on for about 2 weeks.  The problem is that we have about 25 or so other projects that have been building fine within that time period.  We keep 5 builds of each project, so I deleted all but one build in each project to free up some space but the problem still exists.  I'm not sure if the low disc error is even accurate or if it's something weird going on with Jenkins.

Also, the project which is receiving this error is the most recently created project.  Does Jenkins allocate a given amount of memory for each build project upon creation?

Our build options are handled in a *.targets file and here are the settings for this project:

`<Zip Files="@(RepoOutput)"
          WorkingDirectory="$(TargetPath)"
          ZipFileName="$(RepoZipFileName)"
          ZipLevel="9"
          Zip64="true"/>`

Not sure if there is something I am missing here or not, but when it builds it says that line raises the error.

Edit: post targets code

Comment: "Does Jenkins allocate a given amount of memory for each build project upon creation?" No, Jenkins does not reserve RAM or disk space that I know of.

Comment: You should investigate why the build is generating the "consider using Zip64" error. Is there a large file or directory of files that's being unintentionally zipped in the Jenkins build? What the expected zip file size? How much disk space do you have? Are there unexpectedly large files in the build's workspace?